# 64bit Hello world freezes after compiling

Tags: x86-64, fasm

Program compiles, but freezes after starting. If replace the format and include with 32-bit versions or comment out the MessageBox, then everything works fine.

```
format PE64 GUI

include 'E:\Fresh\include\win64a.inc'

entry start

section '.data' data readable writeable

        text db 'Hello world!',0

section '.text' code readable executable
start:
        invoke MessageBox,0,text,text,0
        invoke ExitProcess,0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

        library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL', user32, 'USER32.DLL'
        import kernel32, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
        import user32, MessageBox, 'MessageBoxA'
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no message box? Maybe _behind_ your IDE or console window?

Comment: What does the disassembly look like? Are `invoke` macros expanded as expected?

Comment: @CherryDT, The system issues notification "program has stopped working"

Comment: @Ruslan Not sure, there is MessageBox in cs instead of ds. And mov rcx,0 instead push 0.

Comment: If you get an error message, always put its exact text in your question as part of the [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stack is not aligned to 16 bytes, as the [ABI requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=vs-2019). Add `and rsp, -16` to the beginning of your code, and it will work.

Regarding this exchange in the comments:

> Ruslan: What does the disassembly look like? Are `invoke` macros expanded as expected?
>
> rancid_rot: Not sure, there is MessageBox in cs instead of ds. And mov rcx,0 instead push 0.

I'd recommend avoiding `invoke` and similar macros until you learn what they should expand to. Otherwise you think you write in assembly, but actually you write in a high-level language only resembling assembly, not even knowing what code you will get in the end—thus defying the whole purpose of using an assembler.

To actually learn to call functions in Win64 assembly, see the [documentation on Win64 calling conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I prefer the one to one correlation `WYSIWYG` if you will that what you see in the source is exactly the same in an object dump or debugger. This is not the case with macros.

Comment: @Shift_Left that's my preference too, but I realize that not everyone wants that, so I don't suggest avoiding the code-hiding macros forever.